# Wireless on Letux 400 finds networks, doesn't connect. Why?

Tags: linux

Now here's a question few people will be interested in...

I bought a [Letux 400](http://www.handheld-linux.com/wiki.php?page=Letux%20400) mini netbook and it works fine except for wireless Ethernet.

It finds wireless networks, including mine, and then pretends to connect, after asking for a password, but finally never connects. I tried reconfiguring the wireless network from g to b/g and finally to b only, but nothing changed.

Cable connection works.

Unfortunately all relevant [Letux Web pages](http://www.letux.org/) are hopelessly slow and certainly too slow to use the forum and ask questions there.

Any idea why the thing doesn't connect and how to make it connect? If it recognises networks, shouldn't it be able to connect as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using WPA on my wireless network too. I had to change the wireless channel to 10
to discover any network, then it connects fine.

pahihu

Comment: This appears to work!

Comment: Stopped working... netbook now connects and then announces the IP address is invalid. If I give it a manual address, it cannot ping anything or be pinged. It did work yesterday including DNS and Google.